# How to traverse through Dojo Web Table which is in <Div> Tags

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4hIi.png)I have web page where I need to select the particular element in the web table.In the normal tables we can do it by counting number of rows and columns but in the Dojo page these elements are present in the  Tag.Not sure how to traverse through it to click on particular element.Please find the Dojo HTML code below.

```
<div class="appointment-calendar-item special-calendar-5-items" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" id="uniqName_8_3" widgetid="uniqName_8_3">
    <div class="calendar-item-title">
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="itemWeek" class="calendar-month-week bold">Thursday</div>
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="itemMonthDay" class="calendar-month-day medium">May 19</div>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="itemsList" class="items-container">
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 9:00 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="9:00 am">9:00 am</a> 
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 9:15 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="9:15 am">9:15 am</a>
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 9:30 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="9:30 am">9:30 am</a>
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 9:45 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="9:45 am">9:45 am</a> 
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 10:00 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="10:00 am">10:00 am</a> 
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 10:15 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="10:15 am">10:15 am</a>
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 10:30 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="10:30 am">10:30 am</a>
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 10:45 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="10:45 am">10:45 am</a>
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 11:00 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="11:00 am">11:00 am</a>
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 5:15 pm" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="5:15 pm">5:15 pm</a>
        <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 5:30 pm" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="5:30 pm">5:30 pm</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: <div class="appointment-calendar-item special-calendar-5-items" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" id="uniqName_8_3" widgetid="uniqName_8_3">
    <div class="calendar-item-title">
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="itemWeek" class="calendar-month-week bold">Thursday</div>
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="itemMonthDay" class="calendar-month-day medium">May 19</div>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="itemsList" class="items-container">

Comment: <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Thursday, May 19, 10:15 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="10:15 am">10:15 am</a>

Comment: You have to provide more HTML so we can figure out what is the appropriate locator.

Comment: Okies...Please find the detailed HTML in below comments

Comment: <div data-dojo-attach-point="itemsList" class="items-container">
 <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 9:00 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="9:00 am">9:00 am</a>
 <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 9:15 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="9:15 am">9:15 am</a>
 <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 9:30 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="9:30 am">9:30 am</a>

Comment: <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 9:45 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="9:45 am">9:45 am</a>
 <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 10:00 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="10:00 am">10:00 am</a>
 <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 10:15 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="10:15 am">10:15 am</a>

Comment: <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 10:30 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="10:30 am">10:30 am</a>
 <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 10:45 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="10:45 am">10:45 am</a>
 <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 11:00 am" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="11:00 am">11:00 am</a>

Comment: <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 5:15 pm" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="5:15 pm">5:15 pm</a>
 <a class="calendar-item-time" href="" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Monday, May 23, 5:30 pm" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-time="5:30 pm">5:30 pm</a></div>

Comment: Please paste above HTML code in Notepad++ so that it will be easy to understand.Thanks.

Comment: How many columns does your application show? Can you attach screenshot of your application? Which cell do you want to click?

Comment: Added the comment in the attachment.Please check.There i need to click on the First Available time slot of 9 Am.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click on the first 9:00 am, you can do that with XPath.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'9:00 am')]")).Click();
```

In case you want to walk through all items. You need to get div elements with class "items-container", then loop through them

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> itemContainersCollection = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".items-container")); 
foreach(IWebElement div in itemContainersCollection)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> aCollection = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a"));
    foreach(IWebElement a in aCollection)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a.GetAttribute("aria-label") + " - "+ a.Text);
    }
}
```